# Is building GUIs with Lua possible?

Tags: lua

I'm just wondering if GUI building using Lua is possible. If so, what program(s) should I use (and instructions to get started)?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056592/how-can-i-make-an-gui-application-in-lua

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an GUI Application in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056592/how-can-i-make-an-gui-application-in-lua)

Comment: Not on it's own, you need to use a library or embed it into another language that does. If you are building simple Windows applications you can take a look at how I use Lua + AutoHotkey to build GUI to make various macros and tools: https://github.com/revolucas/AXRToolset

Answer (score 1):

Lua is typically used embedded into some other application, perhaps a game engine, a web server, an IoT system or something else. [Lua has many different applications](https://sites.google.com/site/marbux/home/where-lua-is-used) but Lua cannot by itself be used to build GUI applications. You need to embed Lua into an application that provides bindings to a GUI system of some kind. One such system is [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/) and you can fins many more on the [Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/GraphicalUserInterfaceToolkits).

Comment: Its possible write standalone gui application. E.g. I make basic app using IUP library and build standalone `.exe` file using l-bia program. May be its not wide used but its totaly possible. And you have not embed Lua to any other application. Just use Lua library

Comment: @moteus, do you have an example of this? What's an IUP library?

Answer (score 1):

There is Corona and Love2D engines that essentially are lua gui engines.
You can also create your own lua gui engine. I am developing one for POS machines. It is named Marco Polo, and creates GUI in lua tables that looks a lot like JSON, and thanks to tables and metamethods refreshes the screen as soon as the user makes changes to the tables. It also deal with keypresses and touchscreen with events, passing a function callback to the proper event table, so is called as soon as the event happens.
And, you can also use LuaJIT. LuaJIT allows you to call c functions directly from Lua using FFI, so you can use the usual Windows or Linux GUI libraries from Lua like if you are in C.